# Does parsing an uploaded JSON with ActiveRecord::Serialization.from_json() in RoR open up any security loophole?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, security

I am planning on implementing an export-import functionality in Ruby on Rails.
Now since JSON can include JavaScript, I wonder if anyone could inject malicious code that can be run when I ask ruby to convert the JSON to a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JSON can not include javascript code*. It is more strict version of Javascript object literal synthax.

http://json.org/

*- actually, javascript code could be included in JSON in string, but it won't be parsed.